# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and discontinuous functions

Tags: calculus

Will the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus be useful in evaluating:

$$y=\int_{0.5}^{1} \left \lfloor t \right \rfloor dt?$$

The Riemann sums make this evaluation easy. I, however, would like to know how( if possible), can I use the theorem to evaluate this definite integral. Here, I assumed that $y$ is continuous in $[0.5,1]$ and differentiable in $(0,1)$.

Edit: To be clear about what I wish to know, I ask if I could evaluate the definite integral just by taking the difference, $y(1)-y(0.5)$( second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus), where $y$ is the antiderivative of $\left \lfloor  x\right \rfloor$.

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to talk about antiderivatives of discontinuous functions. Am I allowed to?

Comment: It's left continuous at 1, but I don't think we can use FTC still. Seems a little sketch, but good question.

Comment: Don't you think the floor function is right continuous at 1?

Comment: Well, yes, but it's certainly not two-sided continuous.

Comment: Normally the textbooks of calculus present the Fundamental Theorem of calculus for continuous functions only. It's great that you want to know if these theorems hold for discontinuous functions or not +1. I have given a link in my answer which deals with the general Fundamental Theorem of calculus which is applicable for Riemann integrable functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1900844/72031) where I have discussed the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for functions which are not necessarily continuous.

Next note that the integrand here has a discontinuity at $x=1$ and as far as the interval of integration is concerned the discontinuity is removable and hence we just remove it by changing value of integrand at $x=1$ to $0$. Doing this has no impact on the value of the integral (because the value of a Riemann integral does not depend on the value of the integrand at a finite number of points in the interval under consideration) and thus the desired integral is equal to $\int_{1/2}^{1}0\,dx=0$.

---

In general if we have to evaluate an integral of the form $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ where $f$ has a finite number of discontinuities at $x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n}$ in $[a, b] $ with $$a\leq x_{1}\leq x_{2}\leq \dots\leq x_{n} \leq b$$ such that left and right hand limits of $f$ exist at each point of discontinuity then we split the integral as follows $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\int_{a} ^{x_{1}}f(x)\,dx+\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}}f(x)\,dx+\cdots+\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_{n}}f(x)\,dx+\int_{x_{n}}^{b}f(x)\,dx$$ Each integral on right can be evaluated by observing that the integrand has removable discontinuity at the end points $x_{i}$ and the integrand can be redefined at these points to make it continuous on that interval.

You can use this technique to evaluate $\int_{1}^{2}[x^{2}]\,dx$ as $$\int_{1}^{2}[x^{2}]\,dx=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}1\,dx+\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}}2\,dx+\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{2}3\,dx$$

---

Also to answer your question about evaluating the integral under consideration via second part of fundamental theorem of calculus, note that there is no anti-derivative of $[x] $ on interval $[1/2,1]$ (why? perhaps you should answer this yourself, but let me know if you feel issue here) and hence we can't use fundamental theorem of calculus here.

Also note that continuous functions are guaranteed to have an anti-derivative, but continuity is not necessary. There are discontinuous functions which possess anti-derivative and *if we have a function $f$ which is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and possesses an anti-derivative $F$ (note that existence of anti-derivative is not guaranteed and hence we are assuming its existence here as a part of the hypotheses) such that $F'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\in[a, b] $ then we have $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$*.

Comment: I might know why $[x]$ has no antiderivative in the intervals containing integers. I will use the method of contradiction to prove this. Let us say that the step function does have an antiderivative. If we sketch its antiderivative, we will find sharp turns at integers, suggesting that the derivatives at those points are not defined. But $[x]$ has unique values at integer points. This is absurd.

Comment: @R004: Your intuitive argument is correctbut this can not be used as a proof. You need to prove that derivatives can not have jump discontinuity via mean value theorem. Thus a step function like $[x]$ with jumps can not be the derivative of any function.

Comment: @R004: See one proof here in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/577978/72031

Comment: If I understand this correctly, what $\int_{1/2}^1 [x]dx=\lim_{t \to 1^-} \int_{1/2}^t [x]dx$ is telling me is that I can carry out my regular integration using the SFTC, right?

Comment: @R004 : this statement is saying that the function $y(x) =\int_{1/2}^{x}[t]\,dt$ is continuous at $x=1$. It does not have any other meaning. By the way if you check the statement of first FTC in my linked answer you will find that it says : If $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ then $F(x) $ is continuous on $[a, b] $. So this is just a consequence of first FTC.

Comment: So, the only way to proceed with this integral is to evaluate the limit of the Riemann sums.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61018/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-r004).

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Say we have a function f that is continuous everywhere except a finite number of points on a closed interval and is bounded(and thus Riemann Integrable) on that interval, and a function F continuous everywhere on that closed interval and differentiable everywhere except at the points where f is discontinuous and when it is differentiable, F'=f. Can we still use the rule $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ = F(b) - F(a)?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: yes you can do that. The problem is easily reduced to the case when $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ except possibly at end points $a, b$ and $F'=f$ on open interval $(a, b) $. In that case we have the integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ still equal to $F(b) - F(a) $. Note that continuity of $F$ on whole closed interval $[a, b] $ is essential.

Comment: What about if it is continuous everywhere except at a countably infinite number of points?

Comment: I mean f is continuous everywhere except at a countably infinite number of points, F is differentiable everywhere except at a countably infinite number of points (the same points) and continuous everywhere

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: Continuity of $F$ is essential and the result holds in that case too. Using Cousin's Lemma one can prove that if $F$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ and $F'=0$ except possibly at a countable number of points then $F$ is constant.

Answer (score 3):

$y $ is continuous at $[0.5,1]  \implies $

$$\int_{0,5}^1\lfloor t\rfloor dt=
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\int_{0,5}^x\lfloor t \rfloor dt =0. $$

Comment: I have started learning recently. I will need you to elaborate on this if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

By definitión $[x]$ is defined as the biggest integer notexceding $x$, for example $[\pi]=3$ and $[-1/2]=-1$. The floor function $x \mapsto [x]$ is continuous in the interval $[1/2,1)$; so $$\int_{1/2}^1 [x]dx=\lim_{t \to 1^-} \int_{1/2}^t [x]dx.$$ Also, for $1/2\leq x<1$ we have that $[x]=0$, so $$\int_{1/2}^1 [x]dx=\lim_{t \to 1^-} \int_{1/2}^t [x]dx=\lim_{t \to 1^-} \int_{1/2}^t 0dx=\lim_{t \to 1^-}0=0$$

Comment: I haven't come across the limit notation you used with your integral. Could you explain that? And, I was wondering if I could evaluate the definite integral just by taking the difference, $g(1)-g(0.5)$( second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus),where $g$ is the antiderivative of $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$.

Comment: Ohhh you mean Barrow's Rule, sorry. For your firs question, it is just the definition of limit. For example, consider the function $F(x)=\int_1^x t^2dt$, you know by the second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (Barrow's Rule) that $F(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$, so for example $$\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)=\lim_{x \to 0} \int_1^x t^2dt=\lim_{x \to 0}(x^3/3-1/3)=-1/3.$$ As for your second question, yes; it is possible. Just have in mind that the antiderivat of $[x]$ is $g(x):=x[x]-\frac{1}{2}[x]([x]+1)$. Then you may use Barrow's Rule without problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: That is a huge antiderivative! It fits. This helps. I have question. Why did you take the limit of the integral?

Comment: Because by the limits of integration it follows that $1/2\leq x \leq 1$, note that $[x]=0$ if $1/2 \leq x <1$ and $[x]=1$ when $x=1$, so we will have "two posible values for [x]". To avoid this problem I use the fact that [x] is continous on the interval we are working on, so I can take limits without any problem.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! I believe that the limit approach is a better than the Barrow's approach in this case.

Comment: Yes, let's say it is more "natural".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61010/discussion-between-r004-and-adrian-naranjo).

Comment: I think you should also mention that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and $F(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ then $F(x) $ is continuous on $[a, b] $. Because of this result $y(x) =\int_{1/2}^{x}[t]\,dt$ is continuous and hence $$\int_{1/2}^{1}[x]\,dx=y(1)=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}y(x)=\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\int_{1/2}^{x}[t]\,dt$$ Without this your first equation seems to come from out of the blue.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also you mention in comments about anti-derivative of $[x] $ and provide a formula for it. This is wrong because the function $[x] $ does not have an anti-derivative over any interval which includes integer points. I wonder how you arrived at a formula for anti-derivative when it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can talk about the anti derivatives of discontinuous functions. But if a function $f$ has a jump discontinuity (like the greatest integer function $[x] $ in question which has jump discontinuity at integers) then it does not possess an anti-derivative and hence it's integral can not evaluated by using Leibniz Rule (that is difference between values of anti-derivative at the end points of the interval).

There are discontinuous functions which don't have jump discontinuity and then they may possess anti-derivative. For example the function $f(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$ is continuous everywhere except at $0$. It possesses an anti-derivative $g(x) =x^{2}\sin(1/x),g(0)=0$ and for all real $a, b$ we have $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=g(b) - g(a) $$ However in cases where the integrand is having jump discontinuity in the interval of integration there is still some hope. Here we can not use anti-derivative (because it does not exist) but we can split the interval of integration into multiple intervals via the points of discontinuity and evaluate integral on each subinterval and add these integrals to get the value of the integral on the given interval. Splitting the interval of integration into multiple sub-intervals has the advantage that the function has discontinuity only at the end points and these are removable. So the function can be modified accordingly at end points to make it continuous and the integral evaluated as usual.

For the current question the integrand already has discontinuity on end point of the interval so no need to split the interval and integral is directly evaluated as $\int_{1/2}^{1}0\,dx=0$.

Comment: In order to possess an anti-derivarive it is not necessary that the function be continuous. For example $f(x) =2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x),f(0)=0$ has a discontinuity at $x=0$ but it has an anti-derivarive $g(x) =x^{2}\sin(1/x),g(0)=0$. However it is necessary that a function must not have jump discontinuity in order to possess an anti-derivarive.

Comment: Yes but I was talking about evaluating definite integrals.

Comment: OK I get it now. I didn't mention this explicitly in my answer.

Comment: Again you are wrong. The evaluation of integral as a difference of values of anti-derivarive at the end points of the interval has nothing to do with the integrand being continuous in the interval. All that we need is that the integrand be Riemann integrable in the interval (and not necessarily continuous).

Comment: I don't think so I will give you a example.integerate 1+x^2 from 0 to 3^1/2. Write the anti derivative as 1/2arctan(2x/1-x^2)

Comment: In your example I don't see any problem.

Comment: When evaluating integrals with aid of Newton leibniz formula of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus attention should be paid to the conditions of its legitimate use this formula only when the anti derivative hence found when differentiated should give the  original function in complete interval of integration.

Comment: The function $(1/2)\arctan(2x/(1-x^{2}))$ is not an anti-derivative of the function $1/(1+x^{2})$ because it is not defined at $x=1$. The anti-derivative is $\arctan x$. Note that by definition an anti-derivative of a function  $f$ is always continuous because it is differentiable with derivative equal to $f$. So if you are thinking of creating discontinuous anti-derivatives then there is no chance to succeed.

Comment: See it is a anti derivative but only thing is that it is not anti derivative for that interval.

Comment: We always need to find an anti-derivative which works for the interval because we have to evaluate the integral on that interval. In the current question it can be proved that there is no anti-derivative of $[x] $ on interval $[1/2,1]$. I am objecting to your statement where you demand the integrand function to be continuous because it is wrong. Discontinuous functions can possess anti-derivatives and their integrals can be evaluated using difference of anti-derivative at the end points of the interval. Rest of what you mention in comments ok.

Comment: I agree. Also I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit my answer? By also keeping things I said in comments?

Comment: Also give an example of jump discontinuity.

Comment: Ok, I will add the necessary details.