# Are these two functions equivalent

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f$ defined on the nonnegative reals such that 
$f(x)=x$ for all nonnegative $x$
and the function $g$ defined on the nonnegative reals such that $g(0)=0$, $g^{\prime}(0)=987654321$, and $g^{\prime}(x) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Are these functions equivalent?  Why or why not?

Comment: What is your notion of "equivalent"?

Comment: I suppose I am wondering whether $f(x)-g(x)=0$ for all nonnegative $x$.

Comment: How can $f$ and $g$ be equal if $g'(0) = 987654321$ and $f'(0) = 1$?

Comment: I think if you define a function only on the nonnegative reals then that means a derivative in zero can't exist, because per definition you'd need to be able to take a limit on both ends of 0. So if I'm correct your definition of $g$ makes no sense.

Comment: They are not equivalent. The function $g(x)$ must have some other definition at $x=0$ so that after taking the first derivative it has the assigned value.

Comment: What if instead $g^{\prime}(1)=987654321$ and $g^{\prime}(x)=1$ for all nonnegative $x \neq 1$?  Then would $f(x)=g(x)$ for all nonnegative $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Such a function $g$ does not exist, since  $g'$ cannot have a jump discontinuity. See the question below, or Darboux's theorem.

[Prove that if a function $f$ has a jump at an interior point of the interval $[a,b]$ then it cannot be the derivative of any function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/563771/620957)